# How to create a pdf file from encoded string content - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am getting response from cURL which is an encoded string format of pdf(i guess) - see attached image.

[image]

I am getting pdf file if i directly put the url in browser. Since its asking for api credentials for viewing the pdf, its not user friendly and i am looking for another way to directly download the file.
So i am trying to get the string content of the pdf file with cURL and i am getting exactly what in the image attached(only small portion attached).

Using that string content, i tried to save it as a plain txt file and from there i tried to decode the string text and to create a pdf file newly. After creating i need to download the same.

I could create text file with the string data i got from cURL and could create pdf also. But the downloaded file showing `Failed to load PDF document.`

Below is the code i have tried and i am not sure whether i tried correctly or not.

```
function pdf_download(){
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $curl = $this->api_call->callapi('GET',APIURL."carts/96171/tickets");

    $content = $curl;
    $my_file = FCPATH . '/document/text.txt';

    if (write_file($my_file, $content) == FALSE)
    {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else
    {
            echo 'File written!';
    }


    $pdf_base64 = $my_file;
    //Get File content from txt file
    $pdf_base64_handler = fopen($pdf_base64,'r');
    $pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($pdf_base64));
    fclose ($pdf_base64_handler);
    //Decode pdf content
    $pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
    //Write data back to pdf file
    $pdf_file=FCPATH . '/document/ticket.pdf';
    $pdf = fopen ($pdf_file,'w');
    fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);//Creating a pdf from the encoded content in txt file
    fclose ($pdf);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=tickets.pdf");
    ob_clean(); flush(); 
    readfile($pdf_file);//downloading the pdf file
    exit();

}
```

Comment: Rather than building a "force download" method like the above, have you tried using CI's built-in download helper? It has a convenient `force_download()` method that takes care of all this for you and works like a charm

Comment: Hi @JavierLarroulet, thanks!. I have tried that also. But the result is same. A pdf file is downloading, but showing 'Error. Failed to load PDF document.'

Comment: Its fixed. Actually what i done wrong is i tried to decode the string and i used this decoded string to create pdf. Thanks alot for your valuable comments @JavierLarroulet.

Answer (score 0):

Since streaming a download to the browser requires sending headers, you must not output anything before sending headers. Therefore, you must get rid of:

```
if (write_file($my_file, $content) == FALSE)
{
        echo 'Unable to write the file';
}

else
{
        echo 'File written!';
}
```

If you definitely need to check if the file was written (for debugging purposes, I assume) you may use CI's `log_message()` to write a debug entry in the logs or just set a control variable. For example:

```
if (write_file($my_file, $content) == FALSE)
{
        log_message('debug', "Unable to write file");
        $file_written = false;
}

else
{
        log_message('debug', "File succesfully written");
        $file_written = true;
}
```

Also, there's some headers missing to ensure the file is not streamed to the browser but sent for download, as well as some required to make sure the file is correctly downloaded

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '. mime_content_type($pdf_file)); // since you're using Codeigniter, this will try to use the correct mimetype
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ticket.pdf"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf_file));
readfile($pdf_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong line in the above given code is `$pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);`.

It should be changed to `$pdf_decoded = $pdf_content;`

Since string in encoded format is already getting which is needed for creating `PDF`. So no need to decode it.

Also the above code is reduced as below.

```
function pdf_download(){
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $cart_id=$this->input->get('cart_id');
    $curl = $this->api_call->callapi('GET',APIURL."cart/'.$cart_id.'/tickets");
    $pdf_file=FCPATH . 'document\voucher-'.$cart_id.'.pdf';
    if (write_file($pdf_file, $curl))
    { 
        force_download($pdf_file, NULL);
    }
}
```